# Does a conversion reset the attribution in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

Using the Last Google Ads Click attribution model a sale is attributed to "Paid Search" if there was a valid ad click within the conversion window regardless of any other channel clicks that happened before the conversion.

Once the conversion takes place, does this reset the attribution?

So, 7 days after the first sale (attributed to Paid) a customer recieves an email, clicks the link and makes a purchase will this then be attributed to "Email" or will this still be attributed to "Paid Search"?

Comment: Analytics would attribute it to email as it uses last non direct click for attribution. As far as i know though, google ads would attribute it to paid search if using last google ads click attribution model

Answer (score 1):

Conversions don't reset the attribution source in Google Analytics.   If a customer makes three purchases, all three purchases can be attributed to the same channel.

If you are using the Last Google Ads Click attribution model, then email campaigns don't get any attribution.  Both purchases would be attributed to ads, even if there were an entry to the site from a marketing email in-between.  If you want other channels to get credit, you should choose a different model.

Source:  See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1665189 where it explains the model and shows that the last channel ("direct") is ignored in favor of the ad.